# Having trouble rendering images from data given by the api Reactjs/DjangoRest

Tags: reactjs, api, django-rest-framework, axios

Hell Im trying to solve this problem. Im new to react so if there was something obvious I'm sorry. So I was able to render the images with the data stored into the states and by using the map function using the code below

```
// Import Files
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// Lightbox
//import { SRLWrapper } from "simple-react-lightbox";

// Project Detail Class
class ProjectDetail extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        data: [
            {
                "id": 19,
                "title": "Example 1",
                "address": "Example -address",
                "address2": "Example -address",
                "city": "Example City",
                "zipcode": "00000",
                "client": "Example 1 llc",
                "commercial": true,
                "residential": false,
                "completed": "Completed",
                "featured": true,
                "images": [
                    {
                        "src": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/waves.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "src": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/volcano.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "src": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/city.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}


render() {
    
    const pictures = [];
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.data.map((file) => {
                file.images.forEach((image) => pictures.push(image.src));

                return null;
            })}
            <div>
                {pictures.map((index) => <img src={index} />
                )}
            </div>
            
        </div>

    );

}
}    // Export Component
export default ProjectDetail;
```

but if I try to get data from my django rest api using this code it doesnt work.

```
// Import Files
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// Import 
import axios from "axios";
// Lightbox
//import { SRLWrapper } from "simple-react-lightbox";

// Project Detail Class
class ProjectDetail extends Component {

state = {
    data: []
}


// Mount Data to the State 
componentDidMount() {
    this.handleFetchItem();
}

// Get the project via axios
handleFetchItem = () => {
    // Variables
    const {
        match: { params }
    } = this.props
    // Axios Setup
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/' + params.ID)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ data: res.data});
        })
        .catch(console.error());
}


render() {
    const pictures = [];
    console.log(this.state);
    console.log(pictures);
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.data.map((file) => {
                file.images.forEach((image) => pictures.push(image.src));

                return null;
            })}
            <div>
                {pictures.map((index) => <img src={index} alt=""/>
                )}
            </div>

        </div>

    );

}
}    // Export Compoenent
export default ProjectDetail;
```

And this shows up in the console
[image: consoleresponse]
and this
[image: console repsonse2]

This is my api response using postman
[image: apiresponsepostman]

Im just trying to finish this as it is the last part of my react project.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time! Sorry again if I missed something and or the question is stacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve it. I needed to check to see if the data was loaded for some reason. Instead of doing needed to use to map functions all I needed was to use forEach which pushes each src link to the array pictures I have setup and then use the map function to cycle through the picture array.

```
// Import Files
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// Import 
import axios from "axios";


// Project Detail Class
class ProjectDetail extends Component {

state = {
    data: []
}


// Mount Data to the State 
componentDidMount() {
    this.handleFetchItem();
}

// Get the project via axios
handleFetchItem = () => {
   // Variables
   const {
        match: { params }
    } = this.props
    // Axios Setup
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/' + params.ID)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ data: res.data});
        })
        .catch(console.error());
}


render() {
     const pictures = [];
     console.log(this.state);
     console.log(pictures);
    return (
        <div>
          {this.state.project.images.forEach((image) => 
    pictures.push(image.src))}
          <div>
                 {pictures.map((index, i) => <img key={i} src={index} 
     alt="image")}
          </div>
         </div>
    );

}
} // Export Compoenent
export default ProjectDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, because your data hasn't come out yet, react will give an error because your array contains null or empty data, my solution is you can do a statement like this

```
// Import Files
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// Import 
import axios from "axios";
// Lightbox
//import { SRLWrapper } from "simple-react-lightbox";

// Project Detail Class
class ProjectDetail extends Component {

state = {
    data: []
}


// Mount Data to the State 
componentDidMount() {
    this.handleFetchItem();
}

// Get the project via axios
handleFetchItem = () => {
    // Variables
    const {
        match: { params }
    } = this.props
    // Axios Setup
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/projects/' + params.ID)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ data: res.data});
        })
        .catch(console.error());
}


render() {
    const pictures = [];
    console.log(this.state);
    console.log(pictures);
    return (
        this.state.data ?
        <div>
            {this.state.data.map((file) => {
                file.images.forEach((image) => pictures.push(image.src));

                return null;
            })}
            <div>
                {pictures.map((index) => <img src={index} alt=""/>
                )}
            </div>

        </div> : <div></div>

    );

}
}    // Export Compoenent
export default ProjectDetail;
```

Comment: So I used your code along with code that I'm trying with and still keep getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function". I quite don't understand why